# python count rows from csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

`colors.csv`

```
id  name    rgb         is_trans
0   -1  Unknown 0033B2  f
1   0   Black   05131D  f
2   1   Blue    0055BF  t
```

How do you count how many f & t, (something like below)

```
colors_summary = colors.count('is_trans')
print(colors_summary)
```

Looking for Result

```
is_trans    id  name    rgb
f   107 107 107
t   28  28  28
```

Comment: Uh, what kind of object is `colors`? Is this a pandas dataframe? How is this question related to csv?

Comment: You can make use of `Counter` class from `collections` built-in module, but only if that's not a pandas `DataFrame`.

Comment: import pandas as pd
colors = pd.read_csv('datasets/colors.csv')

Comment: [edit] that into the question please. And you'll probably want to add a `pandas` tag while you're at it.

Comment: how does your output match the input? can you explain plz? do you mean `df.groupby('is_trans').count().reset_index()` ?

Comment: the output should summarize how many f & t are there in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let say you have

```
color_df # dataframe object
```

you can do that:

```
result_df = color_df.groupby('is_trans').count()
print(result_df) # should give you what you ask for.
```

Comment: yess! groupby worked, I did not know, python has this like SQL

Answer (score 0):

and an alternative with stdlib `csv & Counter`.

```
color_csv = """id  name    rgb         is_trans
0   -1  Unknown 0033B2  f
1   0   Black   05131D  f
2   1   Blue    0055BF  t"""

import csv
from collections import Counter
from io import StringIO

settings = dict(delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
creader = csv.reader(StringIO(color_csv), **settings)
headers = next(creader)
counter = Counter((row[-1] for row in creader))
print(counter)

Counter({'f': 2, 't': 1})
```